# Flutter AzureDevOps Setup

Tags: android, ios, flutter, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I am a new flutter developer. I would like to find out whether I am able to use Azure DevOps with FLutter? How do I set it up, so I am able to build and deploy for both IOS and Andriod? I do not have a Mac so I was hoping I could use DevOps tools to help build and Deploy IOS and Andriod apps all in one automated manner! Thank you!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use Azure DevOps for Flutter project CI/CD.

1, First, you need to install [Flutter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com.mcas.ms/items?itemName=Hey24sheep.flutter) to your Azure organization from Visual Studio MarketPlace.

2, Then, you need to create an azure pipeline for the Flutter project.

To create a YAML pipeline, you can refer to [this tutorial](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/yaml/#task-3-adding-a-yaml-build-definition).
Please check out the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Cyaml%2Cbrowser%2Ctfs-2018-2) for more information about the Azure pipeline.

3, Add [Flutter tasks](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/vsts-flutter-tasks#usage) in your pipeline to build your flutter project.

4, Deploy your app with deployment tasks(e.g. [App Center Distribute task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/app-center-distribute?view=azure-devops) or [Apple App Store](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.app-store))

[This blog](https://medium.com/@levelfivecoder/how-to-build-sign-and-distribute-your-flutter-android-application-using-azure-devops-and-appcenter-965382b85b8b) shares a detailed tutorial. You can check it out.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: seriously you managed to do that with those instructions!.

Comment: Is Micorsoft App Center supports flutter apps?

Comment: The extension mentioned in the answer seems to have been abandonded by the author, multiple issues opened since 2019. An alternative to look at is this extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hey24sheep.flutter